# Unable to Display List of Songs in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerView to display a list of songs but am unable to do so. Kindly refer to the code and kindly tell me where am i mistaken. Thankyou.

SongsFragment:-

```
  public class Fragment_Songs extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
/**
 * Big list with all the Songs found.
 */
public ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

public static Fragment_Songs newInstance() {
    return new Fragment_Songs();
}


/**
 * Returns a new list with all songs.
 *
 * @note This is different than accessing `songs` directly
 *       because it duplicates it - you can then mess with
 *       it without worrying about changing the original.
 */
public ArrayList<Song> getSongs() {
    ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

    for (Song song : songs)
        songList.add(song);

    return songList;
}

public Fragment_Songs() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_recyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new Songs_Adapter(getActivity(), getSongs()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, null);
}
}
```

and here is my recyclerView adapter:-

```
      public class Songs_Adapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<Songs_Adapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();


public Songs_Adapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs) {
    songs = theSongs;
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return songs.size();
}




@Override
public Songs_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Song currentSong = songs.get(position);
    holder.trackName.setText(currentSong.getArtist());
    holder.albumInfo.setText(currentSong.getAlbum());
    holder.yearInfo.setText(currentSong.getYear());
    holder.songDuration.setText((int) currentSong.getDurationMinutes());
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

     CardView cv;
     ImageView albumArt;
    TextView trackName;
    TextView albumInfo;
    TextView yearInfo;
    TextView songDuration;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_card);
        albumArt = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumArtImage);
        trackName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.trackName);
        albumInfo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumData);
        yearInfo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.yearInfo);
        songDuration = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.songDuration);


    }



}

public ArrayList<Song> getSongs() {
    return songs;
}

}
```

is my arrayList code correct? I couldnot get it working if someone would help? . Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: i updated the ques kindly re read it thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like your not using the correct constructor in your adapter.
You are using

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new Songs_Adapter());
```

You should be using

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new Songs_Adapter(getActivity(), songs));
```

Comment: tried it still didn't work :/ can u suggest something else? thanks alot

Comment: You have two methods called onBindViewHolder. Use only the one with the @Override tag above its declaration (copy the content from the other to this one) and delete the other.

Comment: did it but now am not able to map in my viewHolder. can you suggest me the code

Comment: i wrote this :-  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SongViewHolder SongHolder, int position) {

        Song currentSong = songs.get(position);
        SongHolder.trackName.setText(currentSong.getArtist());
        SongHolder.albumInfo.setText(currentSong.getAlbum());
        SongHolder.yearInfo.setText(currentSong.getYear());
        SongHolder.songDuration.setText((int) currentSong.getDurationMinutes());

    }   and now it says "method doesnot override method from superclass"

Comment: i got the onBindViewHolder working. But still not being able to display the songList. Is there something wrong with my Song Fragment?

Comment: Your method getSongs() makes no sense.
You are creating an empty array list "songsList" and just return it. Your for cycle is doing nothing.
You need to do something like this:
public ArrayList<Song> getSongs() {
    ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    Song song1 = new Song();
    song1.setArtist("Artist Name");
    song1.setAlbum("Album Name");
    song1.setYear("Year value");
    song1.setYear("Year value");
    song1.setSongDuration("duration value"); 
    songsList.add(song1);
    You can also declare a constructor to pass data to your object. 


    return songList;
}

Comment: yes thanks a lot i got my mistake. But actually I have an arraylist and getSongs() method defined in another class. Can you tell me how can I use my arraylist and getSongs() method in my songsFragment? sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the songs ArrayList but never passing it to the your adapter. Then how will your adapter get the data? Do something like this -

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new Songs_Adapter(getActivity(), songs));
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

This way your songs ArrayList will be passed to the adapter and can be used to populate the RecyclerView.

Comment: hey thanks a lot. I rewrote the code and it turns out I didn't know how to pass an arraylist to other class. Updating the question